# When there are duplicate rows, how do include only the one I want with the rest of the rows?

Tags: sqlite

Here's my table in CSV form

```
id, person, cond
1, "john doe", ""
2, "jane smith", ""
3, "walter white", ""
4, "walter white", 1
5, "frodo baggins", ""
```

I'd like to run an SQL query with this logic: "Select everything, but if `person` is in there twice, then only pick the `person` row where `cond` is not an empty string (`""`).

That result would be...

```
id, person, cond
1, "john doe", ""
2, "jane smith", ""
4, "walter white", 1
5, "frodo baggins", ""
```

I've tried this code, which has failed so far...

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE 
  CAST
    WHEN  
      COUNT(name) > 1
    THEN
      SELECT * FROM table WHERE cond != ""
  END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want all records except those that have a duplicate name with a greater `cond` value:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM MyTable AS Duplicate
                  WHERE Duplicate.name = MyTable.name
                    AND Duplicate.cond > MyTable.cond)
```